# coldfusion replace function not working correctly

Tags: replace, coldfusion

Here is a document, stored in a variable called templlet:

```
{{d

{{h

Dear Customer,

We were so pleased that you have signed up for one of our programs.  Below please find a listing of what you signed up for.

{{r

Sincerely Yours,

John Jones
President  
XYZ Corporation
```

I intend to replace the `{{d` `{{h` and `{{r` with information selected by the user.  `{{d` is a date, `{{h` is a heading and `{{r` is a report.  The code to do this replacement is:

```
<cfset templlet = Replace(templlet, "{{d", "#repdatemm#")>
<cfset templlet = Replace(templlet, "{{h", "#heading#")>
<cfset templlet = Replace(templlet, "{{r", "#letrep#")>
```

The `{{d` and `{{h` are working fine.  The `{{r` is being replaced with `letrep`, but not where it is positioned in `templlet`.  Here is sample output:

```
July 06, 2018

Mr. Joseph Smith  
1632 S. Bailey St.  
Philadelphia, PA 19145

Dear Customer,

We were so pleased that you have signed up for one of our programs.   Below please find a listing of what you signed up for.

Sincerely Yours,

John Jones
President  
XYZ Corporation

Activity Code....Amount.....Note      
EarlyReg.........500.00.....by check  
Parking ...........30.00.......by paypal   

Report Total :...530.00
```

(sorry for all the dots here -- I couldn't figure out how to put spaces in).

You can see that the `{{r` in `templlet` is prior to the signature, but the report is appearing after the signature line.

I've tried leaving more room in `templlet` between the `{{r` and the signature, which made no difference.  I tried putting the `{{r` in a div, which made no difference.  I'm baffled about why this is coming out in the wrong place.  Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: I will have a look at this in more detail tomorrow, but what happens if you use {{r}} as the placeholder?

Comment: Can you share the code that builds the template document?

Comment: Is the actual document content html or just text? If it's html, that could explain why the element are shifting around... Can you post a small example that reproduces the "report appearing after the signature"?

Comment: @snackboy -- the code is generate by ckeditor, and it is awful, but I'll get it together for you shortly.

Comment: @ageax The actual document is html (very bad html from ckeditor).  If that is causing the displacement, what can I do to correct it?  I posted the "report appearing after the signature" in the original question.  Unfortunately this site did not render the report correctly and I couldn't figure out how to preserve the spaces, so I filled in with dots.  But what you see in the question is what I've got.  Re the <cfcontent> there isn't one.  What you see is exactly what I'm getting from a <cfoutput> on templlet (minus the dots and missing the css).

Comment: @BettyMock Do `<cfoutput>#encodeForHtml(templlet)#</cfoutput>` and edit your question to include it. We can help you formatting it for StackOverflow, if necessary.

Comment: I tried that and got quite a lot of output.  Where could I post that for you?

Comment: You can use StackOverflow's own snippet option or use something like https://codepen.io/pen/.

Comment: @alex I put it up on codepen.io/pen-- but how do I direct you to the place where I put it?  (It's an awful mess -- I'd never intentionally write something like that, but as I said the original templlet was from ckeditor.)  BTW is you can tell me how to use the stack overflow snippet option I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @alex  The html I see in codepen.io/pen seems to have the report above the signature; but it is still rendering below the signature. ???

Comment: Save the pen using the "Save" button at the top right and then chose "Save as Anonymous" at the bottom in the dialog. Copy the URL and post it here.

Comment: Alternatively see https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/.

Comment: @alex https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKVaRg

Comment: @Betty Mock I have found the problem. Please see my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the:

```
<table>
```

Enclosing the report is not closed properly.

This works:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="content">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sample.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="betty.css"/> <script type = "text/javascript"> fieldsplitput('moxlet', '�', 'x_1', 1) </script> <p style="margin-left:40px">{{d</p> <p style="margin-left:40px"><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:georgia,serif">{{h</span></span></p> <p style="margin-left:40px"><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:georgia,serif">Dear Customer,</span></span></p> <p style="margin-left:40px"><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:georgia,serif">We were so pleased that you have signed up for one of our programs.&nbsp; Apparently you live in the city of Philadelphia.&nbsp; Additionally we observe that you were referred to us by 191.&nbsp; Below please find a listing of what you signed up for.</span></span></p> <div> <p style="margin-left:40px"><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:georgia,serif"> <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="betty.css"/> <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="persrep.css"/> <style type="text/css"> @media print { table tr.page-break{page-break-before:always} } </style> <HTML> <head> <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="betty.css"/> </head> <body> </body> </html> <div style = "margin:auto;overflow:auto; " >{{r</span></span></p> </div> <p style="margin-left:40px"><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:georgia,serif">Sincerely Yours,</span></span></p> <p style="margin-left:40px"><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:georgia,serif">John Jones<br /> President<br /> XYZ Corporation</span></span></p> 
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset date = "July 06, 2018">

<cfsavecontent variable="header">
Mr. Joseph Smith<br />
1632 S. Bailey St.<br />
Philadelphia, PA 19145
</cfsavecontent>

<cfsavecontent variable="report">
<table class = "reptable" id = 'reptable' > <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> <td>&nbsp; </td> <td class = "repcolhead1">Activity Code</td> <td class = "repcolhead1">Amount Paid</td> <td class = "repcolhead1">Note</td> <td><input type = "text" id = "repfoc" class = "inpbl" value = "" style = "lineheight: 2px; width:2px" > </td> </tr> <script type = "text/Javascript"> thefocus('repfoc') function thefocus(id) { //alert("got to thefocus id is " + id); document.getElementById(id).focus(); } </script> <td style = "padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 10px " class = "repsubh"> State: PA </td> <tr> <!--up counter on this subhead where appropriate ---> <td style = "padding-left: 10px; " class = "repsubh"> Trans. Date: 11-06-2017 </td> <!--up counter on this subhead where appropriate ---> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "color: #141212; text-align: left;" > EarlyReg </td> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "color: #141212; text-align: right;" > 500.00 </td> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "color: #141212; text-align: left;" > </td> <tr> <!--up counter on this subhead where appropriate ---> <td style = "padding-left:10px; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:20px; " class = "repsubf"> Subtotal: 11-06-2017 </td> <!--up counter on this subhead where appropriate ---> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "text-align: left;; vertical-align:top; padding-top: 10px color:630D85 " > <a class = "repbordtop" style = "position:relative; top:4px"> </a> </td> <script> placecount('cnt-2-1','cnt-2-2', 'brk-2-4-1', 'brk-2-4-2') </script> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "text-align: right;; vertical-align:top; padding-top: 10px color:630D85 " > <a class = "repbordtop" style = "position:relative; top:4px"> 500.00 </a> </td> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "text-align: left;; vertical-align:top; padding-top: 10px color:630D85 " > <a class = "repbordtop" style = "position:relative; top:4px"> </a> </td> <tr> <td style = "padding-left:0px; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:20px; " class = "repsubf"> Subtotal: PA </td> <!--up counter on this subhead where appropriate ---> <!--up counter on this subhead where appropriate ---> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "text-align: left;; vertical-align:top; padding-top: 10px color:630D85 " > <a class = "repbordtop" style = "position:relative; top:4px"> </a> </td> <script> placecount('cnt-3-1','cnt-3-2', 'brk-3-4-1', 'brk-3-4-2') </script> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "text-align: right;; vertical-align:top; padding-top: 10px color:630D85 " > <a class = "repbordtop" style = "position:relative; top:4px"> 500.00 </a> </td> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "text-align: left;; vertical-align:top; padding-top: 10px color:630D85 " > <a class = "repbordtop" style = "position:relative; top:4px"> </a> </td> <tr> <td class = 'repsubf' style = "font-weight:bold"> Report Total : <br> <a class = "repnum" id = "cnt-4-1" style = ""> Count : </a> <a class = "repnum" id = "cnt-4-2" style = "; ">1 </a> </p> </td> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "text-align: left;font-weight:bold; vertical-align:top; padding-top: 10px color:630D85 " > <a class = "repbordtop" style = "position:relative; top:4px"> </a> </td> <script> placecount('cnt-4-1','cnt-4-2', 'brk-4-4-1', 'brk-4-4-2') </script> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "text-align: right;font-weight:bold; vertical-align:top; padding-top: 10px color:630D85 " > <a class = "repbordtop" style = "position:relative; top:4px"> 500.00 </a> </td> <td class = "repcolrow" style = "text-align: left;font-weight:bold; vertical-align:top; padding-top: 10px color:630D85 " > <a class = "repbordtop" style = "position:relative; top:4px"> </a> </td> <tr> <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><table>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset content = ReplaceNoCase(content,"{{d",date)>
<cfset content = ReplaceNoCase(content,"{{h",header)>
<cfset content = ReplaceNoCase(content,"{{r",report)>

<cfoutput>
#content#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I had the </table> outside the </cfcontent> for the report.  It is working now.  I wouldn't have thought to look there, and very much appreciate the help.